# Azure-pipeline not able to autogenerate stage or job name when variable-groups are used

Tags: azure-pipelines

**When I use variables from variable-group, then those variables cannot be used for auto-generating stage-name or job-name**

to reproduce.

```
set
variable-group:
--------------
common-var-group
  A = A
  B = B
  agent_pool = somemachine

azure-pipelines.yml
---------------------   
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
- group: poc1
- name: ab
  value: display_$(A)_$(B)

stages:
- stage: stage_ab
  displayName: stage is  $[ variables.ab ]
  jobs:
  - job: 
    displayName: job is $[ variables.ab ]
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - script: echo $(ab)

Expected result is : "stage is display_A_B"
but what i get is "stage is  $[variables.ab]"
the variable is not getting converted to value.
but if you see the result of the script in the step.
it does show - display_A_B
so it does seem the variable is getting the right value.
but not there to display to the stage name or job name.
```

I cannot auto-generate stageName as well , as below.

- stage: stage_$[ variables.ab ]

Ideally I would like to set stageName/jobName itself, since they are what are displayed on environment approval screen or list of job runs.

I even tried using templates via parameter, but still the same issue.

Comment: Hi Han, any update on this issue, have your check my answer? does it answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

I know what you want to do, but this is unable to achieve.

The value inside displayname of stage and job are expanded before the actual thing is executed, and this expansion does not support resolving runtime variables.

The problem is that variable groups only support runtime usage, not compile-time usage at all. It has already been said very clearly here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-a-variable-group

> To reference a variable group, use macro syntax or a runtime
> expression

The correct usage should be like this:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  - name: A
    value: A
  - name: B
    value: B
stages:
- stage: stage_ab
  displayName: stage is  display_${{variables.A}}_${{variables.B}}
  jobs:
  - job: 
    displayName: job is display_${{variables.A}}_${{variables.B}}
    steps:
    - checkout: none
```

Get the result successfully:

[image]